# I have a doubt with the following sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

Which one of these two sounds appropriate?

> What should be my reply to that?

Or

> What should my reply be to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sound appropriate, but one is more formally grammatical.

"What should my reply be [to that]?" is the more casual version. Some people might object to the structure, as it ends the clause with a preposition ("be") and is more complicated to parse, but if you said it in conversation nobody would think it sounded wrong.

"What should be my reply [to that]?" more closely fits the "subject / verb / direct object" structure that is easy to parse: "What" is the subject, "should be" is the verb, and "my reply" is the direct object. It also sounds perfectly natural in American / English conversation.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you!